# Hot reloading a multi-module spring boot application with gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, multi-module, hot-reload, spring-boot-devtools

I'm trying to convert a project from maven to gradle, but I'm having trouble getting hot reloading to work the same way. I can't show the actual project so I've created two identical very simple projects. One with maven one with gradle. These projects contain two modules:

```
project
|____api
|____lib
```

The `/api` module contains a spring-boot app which depends on code from the `/lib` module

In the maven project I can change code in either of these modules and recompile either with my IDE (intellij) or with the maven cli and spring-boot-devtools will hot reload the application. However in the gradle version it only successfully hot reloads code that has changed in the `/api` module.

From what I gathered this seems like a classpath issue. If you run gradle or maven in debug mode it prints out the classpath it passes when it starts the application. Maven includes `<project_dir>/lib/target/classes/kotlin/main`. However gradle only includes `<project_dir>/lib/build/libs/lib.jar`

I'm very new to gradle to I might have some of the build configuration messed up. Here are the two project repo's:

Maven: https://github.com/Perry-Olsson/mvn-hot-reload

Gradle: https://github.com/Perry-Olsson/gradle-hot-reload

Comment: I still couldn't make it work. The best lead so far is this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34237